# Can R Model Fits Have A Constant?

Tags: r, modeling, exponential

I am trying to add a constant to my model

```
 exponential <- lm((log(fallpercent$n_activities)~ 
 ((fallpercent$percentabovebelow1 )+3))
```

This produces the error

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars.
```

I am trying to create a function with the equivalent of y = e<sup>x+3</sup>.

Ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that's the intercept, and it is already part of the regression? That is included by default, as evidenced if you run the call without the `+3` (where it lists `(Intercept)` under `Coefficients`). BTW: it might be more readable (though functionally equivalent) to write `lm(n_activities ~ percentabovebelow1, data=fallpercent)`.

Comment: Is there a way to change the intercept from 0?

Comment: I'm inferring that your model lists: `Coefficients: (Intercept) 0`, in which case I don't know if or how that should be done. It's a mathematic property of the data given the parameters you've provided. The only option I've ever seen or considered is *removal* of the intercept, not trying to force it to something else. (You might want to go to CrossValidated if you want to ask the mathematical question of "is it appropriate to force the intercept to something else".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to create a function with the equivalent of y= e^(x+3)
>   Ideas on how to do so?

Are you just trying to create this function?

```
myFunc <- function(x) {
  exp(x + 3)
}

myFunc(2)
[1] 148.4132
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the intercept in `lm` if you wish. I believe the following might help you. I have used iris as example data.

First with intercept.

```
fit <- lm(log(Sepal.Length) ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
fit

#Call:
#lm(formula = log(Sepal.Length) ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#    1.88199     -0.04141
```

Now without

```
fit <- lm(log(Sepal.Length) - 1.88199 ~  0 + Sepal.Width, data = iris)
fit

#Call:
#lm(formula = log(Sepal.Length) - 1.88199 ~ 0 + Sepal.Width, data = iris)

#Coefficients:
#Sepal.Width  
   -0.04141
```

Here, 1.88199 is 3 your case, etc.